# Windows 8.1 XAMPP and smarty

Tags: php, smarty, windows-8.1, smarty3

I have XAMPP installed and configured. I'm trying to install `Smarty 3.1.18` and I'm running into a bit of an issue.

I've changed my `php.ini` file to add the smarty/libs directory to the includes.
I've unzipped smarty into my `c:\smarty` folder
I made my `smarty\templates` and `config` folders in the htdocs folder
I've also made my cache and `templates_c` folders inside the `c:\smarty` folder.
I made my `index.php` file to include all the directories and made my `index.tpl` file and placed that in my templates folder.
When I run the `index.php` file I return this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template file
>   'index.tpl' <-- thrown in
>   C:\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127

Any ideas??

I have run the `testinstall()` script and this is what it returns :

```
Smarty Installation test...
Testing template directory...
FAILED: .\templates\ does not exist.
Testing compile directory...
FAILED: .\templates_c\ does not exist.
Testing plugins directory...
C:\smarty\libs\plugins is OK.
Testing cache directory...
FAILED: .\cache\ does not exist.
Testing configs directory...
FAILED: .\configs\ does not exist.
Testing sysplugin files...
... OK
Testing plugin files...
... OK
Tests complete.
```

I've checked and rechecked my file locations and directory locations and this is where they are:

```
$smarty->template_dir = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/smarty/templates';
$smarty->config_dir = ' c:/xampp/htdocs/smarty/config';
$smarty->cache_dir = 'c:/smarty/cache';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'c:/smarty/templates_c';
```

Comment: Please provide code how you set templates dir for your Smarty class

Comment: Ok whomever edited my question it now doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is setting correct path to templates, templates_c, cache and config using below methods:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir('full_xampp_project_path/templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('c:\smarty\templates_c');
$smarty->setConfigDir('full_xampp_project_path/config');
$smarty->setCacheDir('c:\smarty\cache');
```

As `full_xampp_project_path` you should provide full path where your project exists for example `c:/xampp/htdocs/yourproject`

As you unzipped smarty in `c:\smarty` and have your project in for example c:/xampp/htdocs/yourproject` you need to set those directories manually.

You should make sure all your paths really exist.

**EDIT**

I've just tested similar configuration but haven't change anything in php.ini because it's in fact unnecessary. I put Smarty into `c:\smarty` and created there `templates_c` anc `cache` directories, I have also `templates` and `configs` directory inside directory of my web server.

I use the following code:

```
<?php

require 'c:\smarty\Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->setTemplateDir('D:\DaneAplikacji\WampServer\www\smarty\demo\templates');
$smarty->setCompileDir('C:\smarty\templates_c');
$smarty->setConfigDir('D:\DaneAplikacji\WampServer\www\smarty\demo\configs');
$smarty->setCacheDir('C:\smarty\cache');

$smarty->testInstall();
$smarty->display('demo.tpl');
```

And everything works fine. Output is:

```
Smarty Installation test...
Testing template directory...
D:\DaneAplikacji\WampServer\www\smarty\demo\templates is OK.
Testing compile directory...
C:\smarty\templates_c is OK.
Testing plugins directory...
C:\smarty\plugins is OK.
Testing cache directory...
C:\smarty\cache is OK.
Testing configs directory...
D:\DaneAplikacji\WampServer\www\smarty\demo\configs is OK.
Testing sysplugin files...
... OK
Testing plugin files...
... OK
Tests complete.

demo
```

so everything works as it should. You should simple use methods I described above to set directories and make sure those directories exist.

Comment: Hello, 
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\smarty\templates_c\5afa44c5bb5ef66ed311d96647082148d7699422.file.demo.tpl.php on line 28

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\smarty\templates_c\5afa44c5bb5ef66ed311d96647082148d7699422.file.demo.tpl.php on line 28

Comment: That's what I got in return.

Comment: I figured out what the issues were.  With some of your lines of code and just making a simple demo.tpl file I made it work. thank you for your knowledge and time.